# JQuery text area character count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use Jquery to count the characters in a text area, here is what i have so far..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script  type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#textfield").on('keyup, paste', function(){

            var Characters = ("#textfield").val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length;

            $("#counter").text("Characters left: " + (1500 - Characters));

        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <form  id="input_form"  method="POST" action="?">
 <textarea  id="textfield"></textarea>
</form>

<div id="counter"></div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Nothing is being output into my div... Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues are there:

1. `.on('keyup paste'` remove comma from here
2. `$("#textfield").val().replace` here `$` is missing from the selector.

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#textfield").on('keyup paste', function(){ // <---remove ',' comma

            var Characters = $("#textfield").val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length; // '$' is missing from the selector

            $("#counter").text("Characters left: " + (1500 - Characters));

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <form  id="input_form"  method="POST" action="?">
 <textarea  id="textfield"></textarea>
</form>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues in your code

1) you do not need comma while passing the event list/multiple events to on method. it should be `.on('keyup paste'`

2) You are missing jquery selector while getting text value of textarea. you should use

```
 $("#textfield").on('keyup, paste', function(){
        var Characters = $("#textfield").val().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"").length;
        $("#counter").text("Characters left: " + (1500 - Characters));
 });
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rv3zcwur/)**